# Embed a pivot table as a picture in an email body in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table in pandas that I created using `pd.pivot_table`.

I also have a way of sending email through python using html style text. Is there a way to embed the pivot table as a picture directly into the body of the email.

Comment: When you say "as a picture", do you mean "exporting the table with HTML styling" or do you mean "creating a PNG image of this table to then include in an email"?

Comment: Anything will work, looking for the simplest approach. Sending an attachments has issues, I believe because of company policy. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super clear from your question, but if you're sending the email through Python and want to avoid using attachments, you could always instead use [`df.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html), which will return a string that is HTML code you can directly include in an email.

Comment: Thank you so much, I never thought it would be that simple